# Why is the class of linear Zhegalkin polynomials closed under composition?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In sentential logic, the Zhegalkin polynomials are the formulae of the form 
$$a_0\oplus a_1 \wedge A_1\oplus a_2\wedge A_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus a_n \wedge A_n \oplus$$
$$a_{12} \wedge A_1 \wedge A_2 \oplus a_{13}\wedge A_1 \wedge A_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus a_{n-1,n} \wedge A_{n-1} \wedge A_n \oplus$$
$$\ldots\ldots\ldots$$
$$a_{123\cdots n}\wedge A_1 \wedge A_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge A_n,$$
where $a_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}$ is either the constant $T$ or the constant $F$. If it is the constant $F,$ then the summand in which it lives is conceptually omitted. $\oplus$ stands for the binary connective that assigned true when and only when exactly one of its operands is assigned true.
Every $n$-ary Boolean function can be realized by one and only one such Zhegalkin polynomial.

The linear Zhegalkin polynomials are the formulae of the form
$$a_0\oplus a_1 \wedge A_1\oplus a_2\wedge A_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus a_n \wedge A_n.$$ By closure under composition, we mean that if $G$ is an $n$-ary Boolean function realized by a linear Zhegalkin polynomial and $B_1,\ldots,B_n$ are $m$-ary Boolean functions realized by linaer Zhegalkin polynomials, then the $m$-ary Boolean function, $H$, defined by $$H(x_1,\ldots,x_m)=G[B_1(x_1,\ldots,x_m),\ldots,B_n(x_1,\ldots,x_m)]$$ is realized by a linear Zhegalkin polynomial.

We can realize $H$ by some Zhegalkin polynomial, $\alpha$. To show that $H$ is linear, it makes sense to show that every $a_{i_1,\ldots, i_k}$ for $k>1$ in $\alpha$ is the constant $F$. How can I prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To show that $H$ is linear, it makes sense to show that every $a_{i_1,\ldots, i_k}$ for $k>1$ in $\alpha$ is the constant $F$. How can I prove this?

If you can prove that, you will be through, but that definitely feels like it is "the long way around".

It will be much easier to show that assuming $G$ and the $B_i$s all have the specified form, you can rewrite your $H$ into this form too, simply by

- distributing the coefficients of $G$ over the terms of the $B_i$s,
- collecting like terms (that is, terms with the same $A_i$), and using the distributive law again to factor $A_i$ out from the coefficients, and
- combining all of the constant terms into one constant term.

Remember that $\{F,T\}$ with the operations $\oplus$ and $\land$ **is a ring** (actually just a different labeling of the finite field $\mathbb F_2$), so you can use exactly the same rewriting strategies for polynomial expressions as you're hopefully familiar with from ordinary algebra.